# Google Sheets Drop Down change automatically bases on cells value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How to make drop-down in B4 until B5 automatically change either to Milo or Coco based on value in C4 and C5.

When i put 0 in column C4 until C5, the drop down automatically changes to Milo.

And anything greater than 0 in column C4 and C5 changes the drop down to Coco.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpY7E.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using an `ARRAYFORMULA` together with `IFS`. You can see the documentation [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en) and [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7014145?hl=en) respectively.

For example:
`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C4:C5="","",IFS(C4:C5=0,"Milo",C4:C5>0,"Coco",C4:C5<0,"Less")))`

This will first check if C4:C5 is blank. If they're blank, C4:C5 will stay blank. If not, it will check if the values C4:C5 are equal to zero. If yes, it will show Milo, otherwise, if C4:C5>0, it will show Coco.

If you post the formula you are trying to use, I may be able to adapt it.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer Daniel H. I have another question. How to make B4:B5 not showing anything if there is no value present in C4:C5.  Because the formula given by you will showing 0 if B4:B5 is blank. I'm sorry because I've zero knowledge about sheets.

Comment: @Insankesepian I updated the formula above with what you asked. If this solved your question, please mark this thread as answered by accepting the answer.

Comment: Hi, i try the updated formula but C4:C5 is showing Milo when no value present in B4:B5. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fAbVvjjgny0twbcIRQIt1-ypJYy9TzugEJAgnvYoF6A/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: I updated the formula in the spreadsheet and in my answer. It now works the way you are trying to use it.